# .htaccess not directing to correct file

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website which opens to /resources/Installer/index.php but the path I need it to open to is /Installer/index.php. I have asked my webhost to help but they have said they cannot help.

I have amended my .htaccess code to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

and now I get an error message Error 404 - Not found Your browser can't find the document corresponding to the URL you typed in.

Comment: `RewriteRule  ^Installer/?$   resources/Installer/index.php   [NC,L] ` try this

Comment: Hello I have tried this, RewriteEngine on RewriteRule  ^Installer/?$   resources/Installer/index.php, but has not worked but has changed to and error 404 code

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you actually ask. Please invest some time to revise your question. Clearly explain which URL should be visible in the browser, which internal path should get called. Try to avoid ambiguous terms like "open to".

Comment: Yes the file system is outside of the main websites folders and I have tried my best to explain my issue I am sorry. the request in browser should be freefaucet.freegear.co.uk/Installer/index.php but it only works on freefaucet.freegear.co.uk/resources/Installer/index.php